# Android kotlin - declare a val within if else condition

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
if (countryCodeValue == "de"){
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.GERMAN)
}else{
    val geocoder = Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH)
}



try {
    val addresses = geocoder...
```

The `geocoder` is showing `Unresolved reference` but WHY ?

I really need it to be this way especially for some other cases otherwise the workarounds would consume more processing power for reasons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're declaring it inside each branch of the statement, which means it's local to that branch only. Just because they have the same name doesn't make them the same variable.

Use this:

```
val geocoder = if (countryCodeValue == "de") {
    Geocoder(this, Locale.GERMAN)
} else {
    Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH)
}
```

Kotlin's if-else expressions are also statements, meaning you can set variables with them.

Answer (score 4):

Just declare `geocoder` like this:

```
val geocoder = Geocoder(
    this, 
    if(countryCodeValue == "de") Locale.GERMAN else Locale.ENGLISH
)
```

Comment: why the downvote? downvoter , please explain it, otherwise it's just useless , coming from pride

Comment: Man, I didn't think it was _that_ bad of an option.  I could have used an explanation, which @TheWanderer did very well.

Comment: people answer with code all the time, you'll be surprised to see the upvote (famous guys) but it's not a reason for downvote, the tooltip on downvote says `answer is not helpful` but it is not like that, sadly it's a trend and many does it so no body cares